# Mockery/PhpUnit: test is successful but it is wrong

Tags: mocking, phpunit, mockery

I have a **Domoticz** class, that read external API.

```
class Domoticz extends HeaterService implements DomoticControllerInterface {

public function getFromApiCurrentHeaterStatus($current_heater)
    {
        $current_heater = json_decode($current_heater);

        if (!isset($current_heater->result)) {
            throw new \Exception('There is a problem retrieving heater status');
        }

        $heater = array();

        foreach ($current_heater->result as $result) {

            $heater['idx'] = (int)$result->idx;
            $heater['status'] = $result->Status;

        }

        return $heater;
    }
}
```

The method `getFromApiCurrentHeaterStatus` returns an array.

This is my test

```
    class DomoticzTest extends TestCase
{

/**
 * This is a copy of real json got from an API call
 */
private $heater_answer = '{"result":{"2":{"Status":"Off","idx":"17"}}}';

/**
 * Test that from an answer as $heater_answer, we can get an array with idx and status
 *
 */
public function testThatWeCanGetAnArrayFromHeaterAnswer()
{
    $right_heater_array = array('idx' => 17, 'status' => 'Off');
    $right_array_we_want = $right_heater_array; // we need to get an array
    $wrong_heater_array = array('idx' => 11, 'status' => 'On');
    $wrong_array_we_dont_want = $wrong_heater_array;

    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('\App\Libs\Domoticz')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getFromApiCurrentHeaterStatus')
        ->with($this->heater_answer)
        ->willReturn($right_array_we_want);

    $heater = $mock->getFromApiCurrentHeaterStatus($this->heater_answer);
    $this->assertEquals($right_array_we_want,$heater);
}
```

The test passes. In effect, with "real" API call (`$this->heater_answer`), we get an array

```
$heater['idx'] = 17;
$heater['status'] = 'Off';
```

Now, I did try to change the property `heater_answer`, changing the idx from 17 to 2, for example, or status, in every case the test passes.

In another words: the real method is it not executed? How can I force the test to execute really the real method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you mocking it? You are not making the actual API call in that method..

Since you are testing whether your method is decoding an actual *heater* answer to a proper format, your test should look like this:

```
private $heater_answer = '{"result":{"2":{"Status":"Off","idx":"17"}}}';

public function testThatWeCanGetAnArrayFromHeaterAnswer()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('\App\Libs\Domoticz')
        ->setMethodsExcept(['getFromApiCurrentHeaterStatus'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $response = $mock->getFromApiCurrentHeaterStatus($this->heater_answer); 

    $this->assertEquals([
        'idx' => 17, 
        'status' => 'Off'
    ], $response);
}
```

By adding `setMethodsExcept()`, the methods defined in that array won't be replaced by a test double. Then you can actually test it.

Comment: I'm mocking because __construct() (for example) initialize the API calls (user/passw/token) etc, so I cannot have original constructor.